# Find subarrays that match condition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Suppsoe I have an array of size 10:

```
x = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)
```

I have an array of function values at these x's:

```
fx = np.sin(x)
```

Now I have a subarray of `x`, say, for example,

```
sub_x = x[::2]
```

How do I extract the values of `fx` at the sub-points in `sub_x`? I.e.,

```
fx[indices of x that are in sub_x]
```

This does not work: `fx[x == sub_x]`.

Comment: Why not simply use `fx[::2]`?

Comment: That's just an example. `sub_x` can be any subarray of x, not necessarily `x[::2]`. For example, `sub_x = np.random.choice(x, ....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
fx[np.in1d(x, sub_x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `np.isin` as:

```
fx[np.isin(x, sub_x)]
```